# SwiftUI Button has extended tap area

Tags: ios, swiftui

I've recently started using SwiftUI and I'm noticing that the tap area of a `Button` always extends around it which creates problems for some of my UIs. Here's my sample code in the playground (Using Xcode 13.3). The same thing can be observed on a physical iOS device:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Tap me") {
                print("tap")
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 500)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: TestView())
```

This demonstrates how far the tap area extends around the button:

[image]

First off, I couldn't find any information regarding this in the documentation. If I've missed something, can anybody point me to a page/WWDC video/a comment where this behaviour is explained or mentionted?

Second, according to multiple discussions here and in other forums, you should use the `contentShape()` modifier to change this behaviour. So I modified the above code like this:

```swift
Button("Tap me") {
    print("tap")
}
.background(Color.yellow)
.contentShape(Rectangle())
```

Which produces this result:

[image]

There IS a difference, but it is trivial and not at all what I need. I need the tap area to extend only to the visible bounds of the button. I've tried to modify the shape using `scale()` and `inset()` both of which kind-of worked. It seems that the `contentShape()` modifier extends the tap area beyond the provided shape. This can be tested by providing your own custom shape. The shape receives the visible size of the button in the rect in the `path(in:)` function. Whatever path is returned from there, `contentShape()` adds its own magic numbers. The only solution I can think of is something along the lines of creating my own shape that negates those magic numbers. Are there any other solutions? Can some of the more experienced SwiftUI users out there share their thoughts on this?

Comment: When you tap you see a circle, it is an event generation area (ie, "finger spot") an d it covers button, so button reacts - it is expected, iOS is not like macOS mouse hot 1px cursor point.

Comment: [take a look at this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685794)

Comment: @Asperi I don't agree. UIKit buttons do not behave that way. And the way it is, it causes problems when you arrange buttons close to each other or close to other tappable views.

Comment: @FahimParkar thank you for the suggestion. I've tried this. They suggest combining `contentShape()` with `onTapGesture()`. Adding a tap gesture recognizer actually seems to add another tappable area around the button with the same size a normal `Button` would have without the `contentShape()` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using `buttonStyle`'s try `.borderedProminent`. A great article is here by [swiftwithmajid](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/02/19/mastering-buttons-in-swiftui/) about SwiftUI Button's. It helped me solved a button issue I was having.

Comment: The style doesn't help with the tap area, unfortunately. It still extends around the button.

Comment: Have you tried just disabling the animation on the button?